# php on nginx stops executing php code

Tags: php, nginx

I recently set up nginx and php.  PHP is running and executes index.php just fine.  It will output echo "hello world!"; just fine.

However after that, I'm including several PHP files and once this happens, it starts displaying the PHP code in the browser -- not executing the code.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There was someone on serverfault with a problem i think is similar to yours, maybe worth checking: https://serverfault.com/questions/247093/getting-php-to-work-with-nginx

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not.